# Жирная точка у элементов списка в css

Tags: html, css, list

Как сделать точку жирной и изменить её цвет в элементе списка при помощи css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Допустим, есть такая верстка:

```
<ul>
    <li>Element</li>
</ul>
```

---

**Вариант А**

```
/* Убираем стандартный вывод метки списка */
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
/* Нужно обязательно указать высоту строки и позиционирование */
ul li {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    position: relative;
}
ul li::before {
    color: crimson;
    /* UTF-8 escape sequence, соответствующая символу "Маркер списка" */
    content:"\2022";
    /* Делаем больше, чем основной текст в li */
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 700;
    /* Элемент вырван из потока, выравниваем отрицательным отступом */
    left: -15px;
    /* Высота строки и позиционирование необходимы для выравнивания по вертикали */
    line-height: 18px;        
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

[image: Результат]

**[Посмотреть пример А](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/J595Y/)**

---

**Вариант Б**

**[Использовать в качестве маркера заранее подготовленную картинку](http://htmlbook.ru/css/list-style-image)**

**Вариант В**

Если элементы списка не длиннее одной строки:

```
ul li {
    color: red;
    font-size: 26px;
}
ul li:first-line  {
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

**[Посмотреть пример В](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/J595Y/1/)**